# How can I copy / select all source code in Safari

Tags: macos, safari, copy-paste

I am able to view the source code of a page in Safari, but I'm unable to find how to "select all" in order to copy it. I can select it manually by clicking scrolling down but it takes forever. Is there a way to select all that I am not finding ?

Comment: In which application do you want to select something?

Comment: got it already from the other answers, Command+A worked . thanks .

Comment: Others might have the same question in the future, they would benefit from some more details.

Comment: Facebook video on safari, was trying to get the source code in order to download a private video , through a private video downloading site (that requires source code)

Comment: Please edit the question with that additional information. Also, https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers has some additional information on what you can/should do if you get helpful answers.

Comment: sure thing. on the answers, well both were correct and basically the same , what I needed to know

Comment: The custom here is to upvote answers which help you, and to accept (with the checkmark) below the voting arrows the one you consider most helpful. This not only is a way to say "thank you" to the people who answered, it also shows that the question has a useful anwer which is helpful for other visitors in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can press <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to select all text in a text area (including the "Elements" and "Sources" tab in the Safari web inspector.

Answer (score 0):

Select everything `CMD` + `A`

Copy the selected text `CMD` + `C`

Paste the copied text `CMD` + `V`